Understanding Gauss-Manin connection on Arbarello's book
I am trying to understand the Gauss-Manin conecction in order to understand the definition of the Period Mapping on the Moduli space of algebraic curves of genus $g$ and its extension to the Teichmüller space,
$\mathcal T_g$ and to the Torelli space, $\mathcal S_g:=\mathcal T_g/\mathcal I_g$, where $\mathcal I_g$ is the Torelli group.
In order to do so, I a
reading "Geometry of Algebraic Curves, vol II", by Enrico Arbarello, Maurizio Cornalba and Phillip A. Griffiths.
In this book, they give a definition on page 220 and they say:
"This is a connection $\nabla$ on the bundle $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb C\otimes\mathcal A_{\triangle}$..."
Going back, on the final part of page 98, it says:
"... Let $\varphi:\mathcal C\to Y$ be a family of nodal curves, then this globalizes to a sheaf homomorphism
$$\xi:R^1\varphi_*\omega_{\mathcal C/Y} \to \mathcal O_Y$$
..."
What does this the $R^1$ mean in $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb C\otimes\mathcal A_{\triangle}$
and
$R^1\varphi_*\omega_{{\mathcal C}/Y}$?
Is it the right derived funtor? If so, I will appreciate an explanation.

Yes, it's the right derived functor of the pushforward functor.
